# Mistakes in Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14

I just learnt the basics of operator overloading. After which I wrote the following code for vector addition of two points in a plane.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct point{
    int x, y;
    point operator+(point b){
        point c;
        c.x = x + b.x;
        c.y = y + b.y;
        return c;
    }
};

int main()
{
    point a, b, c;
    a.x = 1, a.y = 2, b.x = 3, b.y = 4;
    c = a + b;
    cout<<c.x <<" "<< c.y;
    return 0;
}
```

However most of the other operator overloading examples I find are coded very differently, example answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480135/operator-overloading-in-struct). Even though I am getting the correct output using this, is there a cause for concern when I do it this way by declaring a new variable, or leaving out *`const`*?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Also please don't put multiple expressions in a single line separated by commas, that makes the code hard to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Which version of C++ are You using?

Comment: More related to your problem, while [this canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) could be useful (especially the part about [binary arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators)), that's not the only way to create and implement overloaded operators.

Comment: Related: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/)

Comment: Side note: The way you do (`point b`) `b` already *is* a copy of the parameter passed. So you actually could just add x and y to b and return that one: `b.x += x; b.y += y; return b;`.

Comment: Related: [What kind of optimization does const offer in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466642/what-kind-of-optimization-does-const-offer-in-c-c)

Comment: Thanks @Some programmer dude, would the a and b variables in different lines have been a better idea?

Comment: I am using C++14  @Robert

Comment: You might want to consider providing a constructor. That would make your code even simpler: `point a(1, 2); point b(3, 4);`

Comment: The definition of variables is usually okay in a single line, as long as all variables are of the exact same type (so no mixing non-pointer with pointers for example), and don't initialize one variable but not some other. It's the mixing of different things that makes code harder to read. So `point a, b, c;` is okay, but `a.x = 1, a.y = 2, b.x = 3, b.y = 4;` is less okay for many.

Comment: Thanks @Aconcagua your comment helped me undersand why using += was not affecting the actual values in the examples

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk in this case, passing by value is probably better than passing by const reference. Copying `2 * sizeof(int)` is probably less overhead than `sizeof(void*)` + indirection (in many implementations).

Comment: The `operator+()` function should be const too since you're not changing `*this`.
Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/NfanrX

Comment: Thanks Some programmer dude, Robert, Remy, Aconcagua, L.F., Ted for helping me out. Still going through the links, will add any follow up questions I have to this comment section.